# Sqlite3 - Why I can insert string to integer field?

Tags: sqlite

In postgresql, if I do this:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (n INTEGER);
INSERT INTO numbers(n) VALUES('a');
```

I get:

```
LINE 1: INSERT INTO numbers(n) VALUES('a');
                                      ^
```

But, in sqlite3, I got the string saved in the `INTEGER` field.

Why sqlite3 doesn't prevent me from inserting non `INTEGER` value to
an `INTEGER` field?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that they're different databases and don't necessarily conform to the same standard. Postgres is stricter and more formal with how it processes data and will usually throw an error if you try to do something that doesn't make sense. In this case you can't assign a string or character to an integer field without explicitly converting or casting it to an INTEGER. This is the proper behavior. Sqlite (and also MySql) are much less strict and will sometimes accept values even if they're not necessarily valid or meaningful.